# Task coordination and synchronization in spring reactor

Tags: java, spring, stream, promise, project-reactor

We are using spring reactor framework and work is performed in terms of tasks. There is one main task and it creates multiple child tasks. I need to generate some event using the main task when the execution of all child will get completed.
I am aware about the Java concurrency constructs and it can be achieved using countdownlatch etc. But I have read that with reactor framework task coordination should be done using the Streams and Promises.

Need some useful links and examples that provides me more information about task coordination in spring reactor.